# Change org-html-home/up-format locally within an org file

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html

Looking for a way to change the org-html-home/up-format within my org file. I've learned that you can change the variable within emacs via:

```
(setq org-html-home/up-format "<a href=\"%s\">Up</a> , <a href=\"%s\">Home</a>")
```

But I want to specify it within the file, similar to how you would specify options:

```
#+options: toc:nil
```

I've tried:

```
#+html_home/up_format: <p>Test</p>
#+options: html-home/up-format:<p>Test</p>
```

with no luck and documentation is sparse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to enable the `#+BIND` keyword by adding this to your init file
and restarting emacs

```el
(setq org-export-allow-org-bind-keywords t)
```

You can also customize this variable (which allows you to skip the restart).

Then you can assign to export-related variables even if there is no option for them (as in this case), by adding the following header to your Org mode file:

```
#+BIND: org-html-home/up-format "<a href=\"%s\">Up</a> , <a href=\"%s\">Home</a>"
```

When you export the file, the `#+BIND` directive does the equivalent of the `setq` in your question. The binding is temporary and only lasts while you are exporting the file.

You can find a description of this in the "Export Settings" section of the manual which you can get to with `C-h i g (org)Export settings`.

Comment: Thanks, just what I wanted.